# My Temp db is full

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

What to do when tempdb is full ?
I would like to know if tempdb has become full and  what to do if you can't truncate the log?  I want to understand the process why you can't truncate it.

Comment: Is it the log that is full, or the data file?

Comment: If you see an error, please post the entire error message, along with the query that you run and its explain plan.